# Get the number of same string in a list

Tags: python

I want to get the no. of same string in a list

Example

```
list = ['jack','jeen','jeen']
number_of_jeen = getnumber('jeen',list)
print(number_of_jeen)
```

Output

```
2
```

I have tried this so far

```
def getnumber(string_var,list):
      if any(string_var in s for s in list):
            print("This user exits !")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a built-in method `count` that does this.

```
number_of_jeen = list.count('jeen')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Counter` from `collections`:

```
list = ['jack','jeen','jeen']
count = Counter(list)
print(count['jeen'])
```

Answer (score -2):

Try just using a simple counter function. The idea is to loop through the list you have. In each iteration you are checking whether or not the name you are looking at is equal to 'jeen' in this case. If it is increment your counter, otherwise just move onto the next name. Below is an example:

```
listNames = ['jack','jeen','jeen']
    occurrences = 0
    for i in listNames:
        if(i == 'jeen'):
            occurrences += 1
    print(occurrences)
```